# Using a angular directive on the template of another directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to apply a angular directive to an element I create in a template of another directive but it doesn't works if I add it as an attribute in the template. I have the following two directives:

```
// Event Audios
app.directive('audios', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { srce:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<audio ng-src="{{file}}" controls></audio>',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var eventID  = document.getElementById('audios').getAttribute('data-event');

      scope.$watch('srce', function (newVal, oldVal) {
         if (newVal !== undefined) {
             scope.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("data/events/" + eventID +
             "/recursos/audio/" + newVal);
         }
      });
    }
  };
}]);


// Media Element
app.directive('mediaelem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
     $(element).mediaelementplayer();
    }
  };
});
```

The audios directive is used on an ng-repeat to display all the audio files of any particular event. But I also want to apply the mediaelementplayer plugin to all the generated audio tags. Is there a way to combine both directives to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/i3IV1W5q6MChuzEsjuZf?p=preview

Added a Plunkr so that you can better see what I am trying to do. I put a audio tag under test as a stand alone example so that you can see the medialement plugin works in that case.

Comment: Concept works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/02Lxv9znsbuMBGNZnGOr?p=preview Furthering what @ExpertSystem just asked, please provide a code sample or Plunker/Fiddle of what you've tried

Comment: Ok I set up a plunkr with what I have tried and a set up similar to what i have locally: http://plnkr.co/edit/i3IV1W5q6MChuzEsjuZf?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following directive:

```
app.directive('mediaelem', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
       $timeout(function(){
         var eventAudio  = document.querySelector('.audiocontainer').getAttribute('data-audio');
         $(element).attr('src', eventAudio).mediaelementplayer();
       }, 500);
    }
  };
});
```

I omited the directive I was using for the audio tag and used the directive above like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="audio in event.audios">
    <div class="audiocontainer" data-audio="data/events/{{event.id_evento}}/recursos/audio/{{audio}}">
      <audio controls src="" mediaelem>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works without any problems.